# Spring Boot OAuth Always redirecting to HTTP (IBM Cloud CF + Spring Boot 2)

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, ibm-cloud, spring-security-oauth2

Using Spring Boot OAuth 2 on IBM Cloud CF Java Buildpack...

https://github.com/ericis/oauth-cf-https-issue

*I have tried every combination of the below.

**With** this configuration, the application is stuck in an endless loop of redirects, where the OAuth redirect strategy sends it to `http` and then this configuration sends it to `https`.

`http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure()`

**Without** this configuration, users can login via http (undesired).

Full config:

```
http.
  requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure().
  authorizeRequests().
    // allow access to...
    antMatchers("favicon.ico", "/login", "/loginFailure", "/oauth2/authorization/ghe")
    .permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and().oauth2Login().
    // Codify "spring.security.oauth2.client.registration/.provider"
    clientRegistrationRepository(this.clientRegistrationRepository()).
    // setup OAuth2 client service to use clientRegistrationRepository
    authorizedClientService(this.authorizedClientService()).
    successHandler(this.successHandler()).
    // customize login pages
    loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/loginFailure").
    userInfoEndpoint().
      // customize the principal
      userService(this.userService());
```

I've also tried:

1. Server configuration to use `https`

   ```
   server:
     useForwardHeaders: true
     tomcat:
       protocolHeader: x-forwarded-proto
   ```
2. Servlet filter

   ```
   import java.io.IOException;

   import javax.servlet.Filter;
   import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
   import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

   import org.slf4j.Logger;
   import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
   import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

   @Component
   public class HttpToHttpsFilter implements Filter {

     private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HttpToHttpsFilter.class);

     private static final String HTTP = "http";
     private static final String SCHEME_HTTP = "http://";
     private static final String SCHEME_HTTPS = "https://";
     private static final String LOCAL_ID = "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1";
     private static final String LOCALHOST = "localhost";

     @Value("${local.ip}")
     private String localIp;

     public HttpToHttpsFilter() {
       // Sonar
     }

     @Override
     public void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse res, final FilterChain chain)
         throws IOException, ServletException {

       final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

       final HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

       // http, not localhost, not localhost ipv6, not local IP
       if (HTTP.equals(request.getScheme()) && 
           !LOCALHOST.equals(request.getRemoteHost()) && 
           !LOCAL_ID.equals(request.getRemoteHost()) && 
           (this.localIp != null && !this.localIp.equals(request.getRemoteHost()))) {

         final String query = request.getQueryString();

         String oldLocation = request.getRequestURL().toString();

         if (query != null) {
           oldLocation += "?" + query;
         }

         final String newLocation = oldLocation.replaceFirst(SCHEME_HTTP, SCHEME_HTTPS);

         try {

           log.info("HTTP redirect from {} to {} ", oldLocation, newLocation);

           response.sendRedirect(newLocation);

         } catch (IOException e) {
           log.error("Cannot redirect to {} {} ", newLocation, e);
         }
       } else {
         chain.doFilter(req, res);
       }
     }

     @Override
     public void destroy() {
       // Sonar
     }

     @Override
     public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
       // Sonar
     }
   }
   ```

**Dependencies**

```
dependencies {

    //
    // BASICS

    // health and monitoring
    // compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')

    // security
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')

    // configuration
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor')

  //
  // WEB

  // web
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')

  // thymeleaf view render
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')

  // thymeleaf security extras
  compile('org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4')

  //
  // OAUTH

  // OAuth client
  compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client')

  // OAuth lib
  compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose')

  // OAuth config
  compile('org.springframework.security.oauth.boot:spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure:2.0.0.RELEASE')

  //
  // CLOUD

  // cloud connectors (e.g. vcaps)
  compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cloud-connectors')

    //
    // TOOLS

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    //
    // TEST

    // test
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    // security test
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This was resolved. Details on the issue related to this can be found at:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5535#issuecomment-407413944

Example project that is now working: https://github.com/ericis/oauth-cf-https-issue

**The short answer:**

The application needs to be explicitly configured to be aware of the proxy headers. I had tried configuration, but ultimately had to use an instance of the `ForwardedHeaderFilter` class that was added fairly recently to Spring.

```
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {

    final FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter>();

    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The application is likely always stuck in an infinite loop in this environment with the current settings, even without the OAuth behavior involved.

While you can tell the server to use forward headers,

```
server:
  useForwardHeaders: true
```

Tomcat will not trust the `x-forwarded-*` headers from all sources. Certain IP addresses are considered to be internal by default ([RemoteIpValve#internalProxies](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)).

However, in the environment you're using, the reported proxy IP address is likely not in this range. You can configure all IP addresses to be allowed with the following:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    internal-proxies: .*
```

This allows all proxies, but may be acceptable for your needs if there is no way to access the application directly.

Comment: I didn't try the `server.tomcat.internal-proxies` setting, simply because the default is a dynamic range based on a regex and setting the value to `.*` is a security risk that shouldn't be used for production.

Comment: Spring Boot automatically configures Tomcat with `RemoteIpValve` and can be configured with `server.tomcat.remote-ip-header` and `server.tomcat.protocol-header` (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-security.html#howto-enable-https). Spring 5 simplified this with the `ForwardedHeaderFilter` (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-5.x#forwarded-headers). Your answer is helpful and valid for older versions. Since Spring Boot 2 requires Spring Framework 5, I'll leave `ForwardedHeaderFilter` as the official answer.

Answer (score 1):

Because of using Spring 5, decided to go with next solution (security configuration):

```
        http
            .addFilterBefore(new ForwardedHeaderFilter(), OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter.class)
```

*x-forwarded-** header parameters handled correct now.