# Spring security oauth2 redirect uri is not using https after springboot upgrade to 2.6.6

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I recently upgraded the project to `SpringBoot 2.6.6` from `2.1.3.RELEASE` (which in turn upgraded spring security from 5.1.4-RELEASE to 5.6.2). In my project, I have `authorization-code` flow and it uses redirect-uri for both code and token requests from IDM.
And I notices that that the `redirect-uri` used in the token request is different compared to the one initially used for authorization code request. The only difference is it replaced `https` with `http`.

The token request was failing with HTTP 400 error because of the mismatch in the redirect URI. It is working fine with old version of spring boot/security.

Also as part of migration to SpringBoot 2.6.6, we are forced to use the property `spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.foo.redirect-uri` instead of
`spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.foo.redirect-uri-template` since its deprecated.

I've configured the redirect-uri property as below

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.foo.redirect-uri={baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/foo
```

but if I change the value to `https://{baseHost}{basePort}{basePath}/login/oauth2/code/foo` its able to get the token and no issues in log in process.

Any idea why its changing the scheme to http for the token request in exchange for authorization-code? Is there any way to set it with https other than specifying the `baseScheme`?

**EDIT: Provider configuration**

```
foo.base.url=https://fooauth.acme.com

spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.foo.authorization-uri=${foo.base.url}/v1/oauth/authorize
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.foo.token-uri=${foo.base.url}/v1/oauth/token
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.foo.user-info-uri=${foo.base.url}/v1/users/info
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.foo.user-name-attribute=userName
spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.foo.logout-uri=${foo.base.url}/v1/oauth/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=
```

Comment: As far as I remember, it takes baseScheme value from the actual request (see  org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.DefaultServerOAuth2AuthorizationRequestResolver#expandRedirectUri). Could you please share the provider part of the oauth configuration in application.properties?

Comment: @AndreyGrigoriev I just added the provider config in question. I was working fine with old version are you aware of any changes came in spring security releases for this?

Comment: No, I'm not. But these are the commits that are related to redirectUri resolution:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/7cfb17a8a39dbdd0819b64c2b95f10ac85d184af
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/23ce7173803ed50a458b6de4e75bfe7bdb51bc2e
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/commit/0ed919f072d36e83a541482f7d3a34cfe68aff90

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I'm able to resolve this by following this [spring security issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/5535).
And the same is described here in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51500554/6565719)

I added the bean as below

```
@Bean
FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> forwardedHeaderFilter() {
    final FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter> filterRegistrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<ForwardedHeaderFilter>();
    filterRegistrationBean.setFilter(new ForwardedHeaderFilter());
    filterRegistrationBean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);

    return filterRegistrationBean;
}
```

Now I don't even need to split the `{baseUrl}` into finer variables.