# Spring boot - Spring security behind Apache reverse proxy

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, reverse-proxy, vhosts, mod-proxy

I have 3 spring-boot apps :

- front (angular wrapped in springboot) on :8084
- resource (spring boot) on :8082
- authentication (spring-boot spring security) on :8081.

Here my Vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.website.com
    Redirect / https://www.website.com/
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.website.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on

    ServerName www.website.com

    ProxyPass /auth https://127.0.0.1:8081
    ProxyPassReverse /auth https://127.0.0.1:8081

    ProxyPass /api https://127.0.0.1:8082
    ProxyPassReverse /api https://127.0.0.1:8082

    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8084/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8084/


    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

This is working and when https://www.website.com/auth/oauth/authorize endpoint is called, I'm redirected on https://www.website.com/auth/login and I see my login form.

Problem is resources like jquery or css are not loaded cause it tries to reach them through URL https://www.website.com/resources/jquery.min.js (although it should be https://www.website.com/auth/resources/jquery.min.js).

I tried solution here : [Spring-boot with embedded Tomcat behind Apache proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455969/spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-behind-apache-proxy) 
So I have Vhost :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ServerName www.website.com

    ProxyPass /auth https://127.0.0.1:8081
    ProxyPassReverse /auth https://127.0.0.1:8081
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443

    ProxyPass /api https://127.0.0.1:8082
    ProxyPassReverse /api https://127.0.0.1:8082

    ProxyPass / https://127.0.0.1:8084/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://127.0.0.1:8084/

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.website.com/privkey.pem
    Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

And I've added

```
server.use-forward-headers=true
```

in the application.properties.

But then when https://www.website.com/auth/oauth/authorize is called I'm redirected on https://www.website.com/login -> /auth part is missing so I get a 404.

Not sure about what I should set and where to make this works?

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found the solution, if it can help someone :

Vhost must be :

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
...
ProxyPass /auth https://127.0.0.1:8081/auth
ProxyPassReverse /auth https://127.0.0.1:8081/auth
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port 443
...
```

And in application.properties :

```
server.servlet.context-path=/auth
server.use-forward-headers=true
```