# Where is the port 8080 coming from when spring security redirects to login? How can I change it to use port 443?

Tags: grails, spring-security, request-mapping

In my app, when a URL is listed in a requestMap as 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', spring security intercepts and redirects to our login.  This is as it should be. However, spring security is adding ':8080' to the login url, which it should not do. I need to figure out how to modify the spring security configuration parameters so that the generated login url does not include the port (or includes the default ports.)

The problem occurs when a non-logged in user enters a url similar to the following:

> https://whitelabel.innocentive.com/ar/workspace/index

Spring security intercepts and redirects to login. The url generation looks like this (notice the port 8080):

> https://whitelabel.innocentive.com:8080/ar/login/index

I added what I thought were the correct configuration parameters in our config.groovy file (see below). Unfortunately, I still got the :8080 in the generated url

This is happening when the user has not yet logged on.  (If there has already been a successful log on, there is no problem.)  We use RequestmapConfig.groovy for our requestmaps, which is loaded at the time of booting.  Here are pertinent lines:

```
grails
     //Login required
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/board/removesubscription/**'])
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/board/workspace/**'])
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/projectroom/index/**'])
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/workspace/index/**'])
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/federatedLogin/index'])
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/challenge/newChallenge'])
        checkCreateRequestmap([configAttribute: 'IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY', url: '/solverCenter/**'])
```

However, I think the real problem is that spring security is not picking up the configuration parameters properly.  Here are the spring security parameters taken from config.groovy (httpPort and httpsPort are the last two added:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'Person'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'PersonAuthority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'Authority'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.requestMap.className = 'Requestmap'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.securityConfigType = 'Requestmap'

grails.plugin.springsecurity.active = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.successHandler.defaultTargetUrl = '/login/loginRedirection'
// alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.auth.loginFormUrl = "/login/index"
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.afterLogoutUrl = '/logout/confirmation'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.adh.errorPage = null
// removing these config as we want the default bcrypt algorithm
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'SHA' // Ex. MD5 SHA
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.encodeHashAsBase64 = false
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1

grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.passwordPropertyName = 'passwd'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.accountExpiredPropertyName = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.accountLockedPropertyName = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.passwordExpiredPropertyName = null
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
//grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.apf.storeLastUsername = true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.rejectIfNoRule = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.fii.rejectPublicInvocations = false
// added to cause a new jsessionid to be created after login
grails.plugin.springsecurity.useSessionFixationPrevention=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.sessionFixationPrevention.migrate=false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.sessionFixationPrevention.alwaysCreateSession=true
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = 80
grails.plugin.springsecurity.portMapper.httpsPort = 443
```

I would have expected spring security to generate a url with port 443 rather than port 8080:
https://whitelabel.innocentive.com:8080/ar/login/index

Just some background information:  Our app used to listen on port 8080, but we have recently moved to the AWS cloud.  Our IT has put the application behind a load balancer that listens on 80 and 443.  They do not want to add 8080 to the list of listening ports.

Comment: I think the resolution might be very similar to what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25455969/spring-boot-with-embedded-tomcat-behind-apache-proxy (I missed this in my first switch)   Our IT discovered that setting ProxyPreserveHost off made the problem go away, but obviously we don't want that as a final solution, it just confirms we are in the right area.  My issue now is that I do not know where to declare server.use-forward-headers in a grail application... application.properties seems wrong. Should it be grails.server.useForwardHeaders = true in config.groovy?

Answer (score 1):

Just posting this for those who may have the same issue.  Our problem was resolved by adding the following to our tomcat server.xml:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" internalProxies="172\.31\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto" httpsServerPort="x-forwarded-port" />
```

No configuration changes were needed for our grails application, but  our Apache config did get ProxyPreserveHost turned back on.

(One minor note, if we had needed to set server.use-forward-headers,  application.properties was the right place to set it, despite my initial reservations.