# How to properly Redirect from Spring Boot 2.3 to HTTPS when running behind a Google Front End Load Balancer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a spring boot app running on GKE with the Google https load balancer via an ingress controller. The behavior I am looking for is for the Spring Boot app to redirect to https when an http request is received. In Spring Boot 2.2 and earlier I was able to do this with the following code and configuration.

configuration in my application yaml

```
server:
  port: 8877
  use-forward-headers: true # this should make it understand X-Forwarded-Proto header
```

and in my Spring Security configuration I did

```
 @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    /* When the app is running on GKE traffic will come in through the
     * GCP http load balancer. Which will set the X-Forwarded-Proto
     * header to http or https. When the app runs on a dev machine
     * these headers are not set.
     *
     * see https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/
     *
     * The code forces ssl if the x forwarded proto header is present
     * as that indicates the app is online and accessible to the
     * wider internet.
     *
     */
    http.requiresChannel()
        .requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
        .requiresSecure();
   // more stuff  omitted  
 }
```

In Spring Boot 2.3 `server.use-forward-headers` was deprecated I changed my config to be

```
server:
  port: 7777
  forward-headers-strategy: native
  tomcat:
    remoteip:
      protocol-header: "X-Forwarded-Proto"
      remote-ip-header: "X-Forwarded-For"
```

I made no changes to the code that requires Secure channel. However, when a request  like https://example.com arrives at boot through the GCP load balancer it is not being recognized as  a secure connection and a redirect https://example.com is sent from spring boot. This causes the browser to say that an infinite redirect loop has been detected.

**Question** What is the correct way to redirect from http to https on Spring Boot 2.3 running on GKE behind a GCP load balancer configured via and Ingress controller?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot is relying on Tomcat to evaluate the incoming request to determine if the request should  be considered "secure". Tomcat [remote IP valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html) is looking  at two bits of information to evaluate if a request is secure.

1. The ip address of the load balancer / proxy that sent the request to tomcat
2. The value of the `x-forwarded-proto` http header

The ip address of the load balancer which is called internal proxy in tomcat config   must be on the trusted list and the `x-forwaded-proto` must be `https` for tomcat to consider the request secure. Otherwise, a  redirect is sent.

The google load balancer is sending the request with `x-forwaded-proto: https` but the source ip is one from the [google range](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https#source_ip_addresses) `35.191.0.0/16` and `130.211.0.0/22` so tomcat was considering https requests from the GCP loadbalancer to be insecure sending back a redirect. Thus causing the infinite redirect loop that the browser complaining about.

Spring Boot Configures the tomcat remote ip address using using  the property `server.tomcat.remoteip.internal-proxies` which has default values for private ip  addresses from RFC 1918 using the regex below.

```
10\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|192\\.168\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|169\\.254\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|127\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|172\\.1[6-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|172\\.2[0-9]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|172\\.3[0-1]{1}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|::1
```

Tomcat does not know how to compare ip address ranges so the google source ips must be converted into a regex for this to work.

```
server:
  port: 7777
  forward-headers-strategy: native
  tomcat:
    remoteip:
      protocol-header: "X-Forwarded-Proto"
      remote-ip-header: "X-Forwarded-For"
      internal-proxies: ".*" # should Java regex to match ip address range of the load balancer servers. Not a best practice to trust all ip addresses.
```

Comment: In my case, fixed by using `ForwardedHeaderFilter ` https://stackoverflow.com/a/67377536/986942