# How to make spring boot app run on alternate port?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a spring boot (2.5.3) app running on a centOS VM behind a firewall. I normally build a fat jar, then run it with a config passed via CLI:

1. `mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage`
2. `java -jar target/service.jar --spring.config.location=/path/to/config.properties`
3. run `curl` GET commands: `curl --key /a/b --cert /x/y "https://server-name:8767/path?arg=..."`

It works using port 8767 set in the config, and I chose this port a while back randomly.

Since then, I've tried to see if I could make it work with a different port. I opened more ports on the linux `public` firewall-cmd zone, including 8768 & 9000. Problem is that no matter what I try, the only port I can get the app to run on is 8767. Seems like I've somehow hard-wired it to that port!

Normally `server.port` is set in the config, but even if I pass another port `--server.port=xxxx` via cli, the app runs, and logs show it **is** exposed to xxxx; however, curl can consistently *only* access 8767, and other ports time out. Or if I set `server.port=xxxx` in the config, same outcome.

What do I need to do to use a different port? (I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356829/how-to-run-spring-boot-on-port-443)...would it help me?)

Dependencies (nothing special)
Dependencies (nothing special)

```
<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
</parent>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**UPDATE**: @Vinit - my main class is exactly like yours, except a std println I have to let me know it's running:

```
System.out.println("Running...");
```

As for my application.properties, I cannot paste them as I'm behind a firewall, but they are basically below, and there are more than one of each:

```
logging.level
server.port=xxxx  // as described above, i've tried declaring here or cli
server.ssl
# custom auth properties
customauth.url
spring.profiles.active
spring.application.name
spring.task.scheduling
spring.jmx.enabled
swagger
management.endpoints
sanitization
spring.jackson
```

On another note, I run

```
sudo netstat -nlp | grep "<port>"
```

...before I run the app (where  is the port I have either in my config or passed CLI), and no results. Then I run the app, repeat the `netstat` call, and that port is listening sure enough. But same thing: if 8767, all is well; but if 8768, time out.

Comment: 1. can you just check your Main class, how you are executing SpringApplication?   2. can you check if there is existing application running on port 8767

Comment: You are using ssl, are you sure there is no web server on that port like httpd or nginx in front of your java app?

Comment: @slindenau pretty sure. I'll check and get back to you when I'm able to check in a couple of days unfortunately. Might have to repost this question then

Comment: @kus I have a basic spring boot main class annotated with SpringBootApplication. Nothing fancy. So if I can only get my app to run on 8767, why would there also be something else running on that?

Comment: @kus If there were something else on 8767, then my app would not run

Answer (score 1):

Spring boot takes into account cli arguments when you pass the arguments to SpringApplication.run method in the main method. Main class should look like this -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Pass args as argument to run method and it should take cli arguments into account. With this class, if --server.port=8080 is used as cli argument, then spring application should run on 8080 port.

Comment: that is the standard, i know, but my issue remains

Comment: Can you please share your class and config.properties.

Comment: Yes @Vinit see UPDATE above

Answer (score 0):

this is the order of how spring boots evaluates the different approaches of setting the server port are:

1. embedded server configuration
2. command-line arguments
3. property files
4. main @SpringBootApplication configuration

so two typical issues if the server.port parameter does not work are overridden behavior in a WebServerFactoryCustomizer or in your main method of the SpringBootApplication